# JSF2.0 - CSS-Change is getting lost during lifecycle

Tags: javascript, css, jsf-2, onclick

My intention is to implement a *h:outputLink* with an *onClick*-Event.
The *onClick*-Event calls a javascript-function, which should change the background-color of a *h:panelGroup* (*DIV*).

Here are the code-snipplets:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function activate(menuId) {
        $(".menu_"+menuId).css( "background", "red" );
    }
</script>

..

<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="menu" style="" class="menu_#{menu.id}">
    <h:outputLink id="menuLevel0" class="menuLevel0" action="" onclick="activate(#{menu.id})">
        ..
    </h:outputLink>
</h:panelGroup>
```

If the link is clicked, the *DIV* behind the *h:panelGroup* changes it´s color to red, but immediately changes to white again. (default background-color).

It seems as if the *DIV* gets red during the build of the response. And that the color changes to default again, because JSF renders the page and looses the css-change.
Could this be the right explanation of what is happening?

My question now is, how can I change the color of the *h:panelGroup* "permanently"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` gets a red background but then the normal action of your link is proceeded by the browser, i.e. navigating to the server. Once the loopback is done you loose the background color.

To make it working as you wish you need to tell the browser to not launch the HTTP request when the link is clicked. You can simply:

```
<h:outputLink id="menuLevel0" class="menuLevel0" action="" onclick="activate('#{menu.id}'); return false;" >
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.
Unfortunately I need the HTTP request.
The idea behind my implementation is, that a menu is build on server side.
If a menuitem (link) is clicked, an index (URL-parameter) is sent to the server and the menu is generated again concerning the index.
To activate or better highlight the chosen menuitem, I wanted the client side to handle the colors for it.
One idea would be to handle the colors on the server side too. In this case I would not have to bother about the disappearing color.
I have no idea how it would work properly, when the client would handle the color.

Comment: use a css class and apply dynamically the class on the correct link in your jsf